# Detect elements inside Canvas Tag: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent

Is there a way to detect any elements (id, classes, or tags) that are inside of a canvas tag? I am looking to be able to console log any elements that I mouse over inside the canvas tag like so:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover',function(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    console.log(id)
})
```

Assuming that when I mouse over a canvas tag, it logs out elements.Pipe dream?

Comment: you can't see any sub-elements inside a <canvas>, so no...

Comment: @dandavis there is no sub-elements inside a CanvasElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse event will indicate the canvas object, but not individual items drawn on the canvas. The canvas element is a drawing surface. When you draw something (e.g. path, text, image) on the canvas, pixels are painted on the surface but there is not any information stored concerning what was painted.